# VBA arrays sorting issues

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sorting, highlight

I am trying to use an array to highlight specific rows in my data. 
As shown in the picture, i want to extract the maximum positive profit($) and maximum negative profit($) for each respective serial numbers and highlight it in yellow. For example, Tom123's maximum +ve profit = 100 and -ve profit =-74 , thus both values are highlighted in yellow.

I already know how to highlight cells in vba, but i do not know how to get the rows that i need to highlight. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where is your code so far?

Comment: Hi Nick, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Questions that include code ([mcve]) are most likely to receive assistance.

Comment: Arw you open to other methods that dont require coding, like conditional formatting, autofilter or pivot tables ?

Comment: @ashleedawg Yes i am open up to all ideas. The problem is that this needs to be applied to multiple sets of data with a variable number of lines as the data changes daily.

Comment: It isn't sorting issue. This is "highlighting" problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Add a column to identify if the column C = max profit or max loss

### step 1

In `D2`, write `=IF(OR(C2=MAX(IF((A:A=A2)*(C:C>=0),C:C,"")),C2=MIN(IF((A:A=A2)*(C:C<0),C:C,""))),TRUE,"")` then press `ctrl+shift+enter`.

### step 2

drag `D2` down.

then you will see:
[image]

### step 3

highlight `A:C` if `D == true` with conditional formatting

Comment: Hi! I have tried following your steps, but the output on the cell is #VALUE!, am i missing out any steps?

Comment: I add my picture for your reference.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get the result i want.I am still learning the basics of array formulas so this much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, your formula works great on a single data set. Unfortunately, me and my team need to work with multiple large data sets. I feel like pasting the array formula is a bit too time consuming and complicated for an average user. Is there a way i can do this with VBA? I have tried using VBA to input the array formula into the column but this crashes my excel.

Comment: Hi, @Nick. As David Zemens said, you may need to take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read  read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  I offered my answer for your single column question.  If you feel my answer do help on you,  please select my answer as best.  If you have multiple-column question, please ask a new question.

Comment: Hi @PaichengWu, the question is the same, however i would like to use VBA instead of excel formulas. Thanks!

Comment: Time consuming issue will be improved, if you replace `A:A` with `A2:A10000` and  `C:C` with  `C2:C10000`.  Which make EXCEL calculate a given number of rows, not all rows.